# Get unique id of type using GDB Python API

Tags: python, c++, gdb, gdb-python

I am writing some GDB extension using GDB Python API to be used for C++ applications.

I need to write some index over detected types in debugged process/coredump.
[`gdb.Type` class](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html#Types-In-Python) has `__eq__` defined but is not hashable thus can not be used as a key in `dict` or `set`.

The workaround I am trying to implement is to get unique identifiers for `gdb.Type` objects. `str(gdb_type)` looks very good but this solution is not bulletproof as some types are nameless, for instance take a loot at this one:

```
typedef struct {
} typedeffed_enum;
```

For this one expression `str(gdb.lookup_type('typedeffed_enum').strip_typedefs())` will evaluate to `'struct {...}'` (at least for my compiler and `gdb`) which is totally not unique.

Such types also have `gdb_type.name is None` names so this is not perfect too.

`id(gdb_type)` may give different values for same types as `gdb.Type` objects are not unique for each C++ type. So this does not work at all.

Another idea was to get the location (filename and line number) where a type was defined but I could not find a way to get a type's symbol. If you know how to do it, please share.

Is there any way to identify a `gdb.Type` with compareable and hasheble value?

PS Edited little bit to make the example more precise.